# Does a Request timed out HttpException cause the w3wp.exe process to die or recycle

Tags: .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

Does a HttpException

> Request timed out

or

> The request has been aborted

Cause the w3wp.exe process to die or recycle?

As we are getting a quite a few of these **Warnings**

We are using IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 Server R2; ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0;

Here is the message from the event log:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0
Date:          18/10/2011 09:40:50
Event ID:      1309
Task Category: Web Event
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      XXXXXX-XXXX
Description:
Event code: 3001 
Event message: The request has been aborted. 
Event time: 18/10/2011 09:40:50 
Event time (UTC): 18/10/2011 08:40:50 
Event ID: ef899a8bafa149488029502499a212ec 
Event sequence: 1887760 
Event occurrence: 55 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-2-129630856526919915 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebService\ 
    Machine name: XXXXXX-XXXX 

Process information: 
    Process ID: 30192 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Request timed out.



Request information: 
    Request URL: http://subdomain.example.com/File.axd?key1=value1&key2=value2
    Request path: /File.axd 
    User host address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 47 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace: 


Custom event details:
```

Answer (score 1):

An [UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) can cause your AppPool to recycle/crash.  I suggest adding a UnhandledException handler to find what is causing the `HttpException`.

[Gracefully Responding to Unhandled Exceptions - Processing Unhandled Exceptions](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111700/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091306-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Rick. But would this warning have recycled/crashed the app pool?